# Outgoing Email Sending Issue in Godaddy Windows 2012 VPS

Tags: vps, outgoing-mail

i'm trying to send email from web Application deployed in Godaddy Windows 2012 Vitual Private Server.

Error Displayed "Server actively refused the connection".

Email send from my local system, but outgoing email is not working on Godaddy Hosting.

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient()) { 
    var credential = new NetworkCredential { 
        UserName = "user@outlook.com", 
        Password = "password" }; 
    smtp.Credentials = credential; 
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
    smtp.Port = 587; 
    smtp.EnableSsl = true; 

    await smtp.SendMailAsync(message); 

    return RedirectToAction("Sent"); 
}
```

Comment: I'm using ASP .Net MVC 4.5 in web application technology.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    var credential = new NetworkCredential
                    {
                        UserName = "user@outlook.com",
                        Password = "password" 
                    };
                    smtp.Credentials = credential;
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                    return RedirectToAction("Sent");
                }

Comment: this is the code i'm using  #Karl Gjertsen

Comment: The code has been added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, try adding:

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Before:

```
smtp.Credentials = credential;
```

Since June of 2016, Gmail changed its DMARC policy from `p="none"` to `p="reject"`.

Any emails sent using a from address ending with `@gmail.com`, will have to originate from within Gmail's infrastructure.

You will need to use an email sending service, such as SendGrid ([www.sendgrid.com](http://www.sendgrid.com)) or mailgun ([www.mailgun.com](http://www.mailgun.com)).

You should be using one of these anyway, as they help you keep off spam blacklists and provide lots of other benefits, including details of showing you if emails have been blocked due to bad email addresses, spam reports, etc.

More information on what DMARC is and how it works is available [in this article](https://sendgrid.com/blog/what-is-dmarc) on the Sendgrid blog.

Comment: There is no issue with me in sending from any smtp.Host.
I've tried almost every smtp.Host.
 Like

'smtp.gmail.com' For Google

'smtp-mail.outlook.com' For Outlook.

But nothing works

Comment: That would depend on the host providers policies. For example Google is stopping you.

Comment: I'm using Godaddy Virtual Private Server Hosting Services. So, it means i've to contact Godaddy to resolve my issue.

'relay-hosting.secureserver.net' Godaddy is using this smtp.Host to send email. But this also not working.

Comment: yup, i've tried port 25. i also tried port 587. but both not working

Comment: Set up a free sendgrid account and try their settings.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; `.

Comment: Ok i'll apply this setting. & let u know if it's working.

Comment: Thanks. It's Working Now